# set NSMutableDictionary from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I use a `.plist` file to load some standard info in to a `NSMutableArray` then will setup a `NSMutableDictionary` to get from Array the information and displayed in `UTTexFiled` / `UILable`

I used in past the setting up in `prepareForSegue` like this:

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setLinkImg:(arrayCollection)[index.row][@"image"]];
```

This is my `NSMutableArray` and get the data from plist:

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dataDb" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray * myData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.database = myData;
```

and `data` is my `NSMutableDictionary` now how can setUp my `data` with `database` like a segue, but never change the view?

like a similar to `[database setObject: data];` and then use to populate a `UITexField` like a  `self.name.text = (data)[@"name"];`

Thanks for that.

Comment: I expected a magic wand... i ask a question and i hope in a constructive answer, so you says to insert each key manually, how?

Comment: By writing software.  A loop.  Read elements.  Figure out what the key is.  Write the element and its key.  And before you start, don't forget to create the dictionary.